# Select everything from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two joined tables:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

The question: In query results, id will always be taken from secondary table defined in SELECT statement?

For example:

if I use `select t1.*, t2.*` - in results id will be t2.id

if I use `select t2.*, t1.*` - id will be t1.id.

Is this good practice to use 'merged' result, or should I avoid ambiguity, and always define columns strictly?

Comment: In my hopinion you answered yourself: try to avoid ambiguity. Using the star selector is almost always considered bad practice.

Comment: I agree with @AlessandroCifani. In general, use `*` only for convenience when running one-off queries manually.

Comment: I think, it doesn't make difference. Because both of ids from two tables are the same and after running query, it fetches all the possible results.

Comment: @Pokies: he joins `t1.id` with `t2.t1_id`, not with `t2.id` so I believe they won't be the same.

Comment: I think, They are the same with different field names. When you join two tables, You should be aware that the fields you join, Should have the same domain and in fact the same type. In such a situation you consider the join concept @AlessandroCifani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the sql query will return all columns with the same name from all tables, not just the last one, unless you use a natural join (`table1 inner join table2 using(column)`).

If you use some kind of a component that stores the results in associative arrays, then these components usually use only the field names as key, therefore they return only the last column's value from those that have the same name.

However, it is a good practive to use an alias if you want to return more than 1 column that has the same name in the database.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I forgot to mention that I'm using laravel eloquent, so it returns me associative array, so thats why i'm getting only one id. I was asking because when you have a lot columns, they don't look very good in the code context. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use tablename with alias and get to use like this. It would be best practice to run query.Mention your column names even though it has many columns. You can order your display.

```
 SELECT t1.columnName1, t2.columnName2 FROM tablename1 t1 INNER JOIN tablename2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Your sample query does not use alias.

Comment: ok then what is the use of t1 and t2 here .. its not an alias?? Thanks

Comment: They are **table** aliases, but not **field** aliases. The issue is with the **field** names.